# How to send integer as parameter to servlet using $.ajax get?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I need to obtain an attribute from my Model project from my web application using java, but i need to send and integer as a parameter as well. I read the JQuery API Doc, but I'm very new to AJAX and JQuery and I still find it difficult to understand.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
    $.get('ServletControlB', function (responseText) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
        $('#divnombre').text(responseText);         // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somediv" and set its text content with the response text.
    });
});
```

This is my ServletControlB doGet function:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    int x; // x = parameter recieved from AJAX
    //data is an instance from the Model class
    String text = data.getNews().getNewsInPosition(x).getTitle(); //I send correct postition to my ArrayList

    response.setContentType("text/html");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    response.getWriter().write(text);
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `data object` of [jquery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('ServletControlB',{id:1}, //<-- data object having id as key
        function (responseText) {
          $('#divnombre').text(responseText);
    });
});
```

And in java use,

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the request parameter received as String to an Integer.

```
String x = request.getParameter("yourParameterName");   //get the parameter as String
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(x); //set the parameter here
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending a GET request from jquery, so append query param in URL:

```
 $.get('ServletControlB?yourparam=paramValue', function (responseText)
```

and you can retrieve in servlet doGet as mentioned here:

```
 String yourParamValue = request.getParameter("yourparam");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
    $.get('ServletControlB?x=' + valueOfX, function (responseText) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
        $('#divnombre').text(responseText);         // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somediv" and set its text content with the response text.
    });
});
```

in your controller do the following

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    int x = request.getParameter("x").toString() ; 
    //data is an instance from the Model class
    String text = data.getNews().getNewsInPosition(x).getTitle(); //I send correct postition to my ArrayList

    response.setContentType("text/html");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    response.getWriter().write(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to change your front end like below.

```
$.get('ServletControlB',{ param: '1' }, function (responseText) { 
        $('#divnombre').text(responseText);        
    });
```